# How do I set a password for root and skip creating an additional user during Ubuntu 14.04 Server installation?

Tags: password, system-installation, configuration, users, root

It appears that Ubuntu 14.04 **Server** disabled the root account during installation (by not setting its password). I have been unable to find any way to set the password for the root user during the installation process.

***Is there any way set root's password during install?*** Or do I need to create a non-root user, login as that user after completing installation, and manually set root's password to re-enable the root account, then delete the other non-root user?

I am trying to have as bare an installation as possible for cloning in a virtualized environment. (I do not need to be counseled on the proper use, or lack of use, of the root account.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a kickstart script/file to automate the build.
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/ia64/automatic-install.html

There is even mention of a `rootpw --disabled` command, so you may be able to *enable* and set a root password.

Be warned, that is an older guide. This page indicates upkeep of the guides has fallen behind, so you may want to do some deep digging before depending on this page.
https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/

Comment: The updated version for that page can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html.  Pre-seeding is the replacement term for kickstarting, and can be used to automate most or all of your installation.